# Rails: update_column works, but not update_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, updates

I have a simple model:

```
class Reply < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :body
  belongs_to :post
end
```

In my controller, I have a simple update method:

```
def update
  @reply = Reply.find(params[:id])
  if @reply.update_attributes!(params[:reply])
    render :js => "alert('I am trying to update!')"
  else
    render :js => "alert('<%= @reply.errors %>')"
  end
end
```

This doesn't throw an error, but neither does it actually update the reply. Instead, I get the "I am trying to update!" message, like everything worked. But when I reload the page and look at the reply, it has the same text. It hasn't actually been updated. If I replace update_attributes with:

```
@reply.update_column(:body, params[:reply][:body])
```

It works fine. If I use:

```
@reply.update_attribute(:body, params[:reply][:body])
```

It once again doesn't work. Any idea what's going?

In my log, I have this:

```
Started PUT "/posts/2/replies/20" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-01-19 10:39:57 -0600
Processing by RepliesController#update as JS
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Xot7E+ldXiBm0hVvw5XUP/U5guJU2g8e4QaLbDVGzDE=", "reply"=>{"body"=>"Updated text."}, "commit"=>"Submit Revision", "post_id"=>"2", "id"=>"20"
[1m[35mUser Load (1.0ms)[0m  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
[1m[36mReply Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `replies`.* FROM `replies` WHERE `replies`.`id` = 20 LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  BEGIN
[1m[36mPost Load (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE `posts`.`id` = 2 LIMIT 1[0m
[1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  COMMIT
Rendered replies/_reply_content.html.erb (502.0ms)
Rendered replies/update.js.erb (505.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 849ms (Views: 484.0ms | ActiveRecord: 94.0ms)
```

Comment: what version of rails are you using?

Comment: I'm using version 3.2.11, the latest in the 3.2 branch.

Comment: You can use `update_attributes!` to see why it's not saving.

Comment: Where is the "Post Load" coming from? It's in your parameters and your log, but not in your controller code.

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it's coming from my view. There's a line that calls reply.post to test for user permissions.

Comment: @timothythehuman why is it rendering `update.js.erb ` wrapped the code in respond_to format block

Comment: @Viren If I understand your question correctly, it's because update uses a remote call and returns a .js file.

Answer (score 92):

The three methods you are using do different things:

- `update_attributes` tries to **validate** the record, calls **callbacks** and **saves**;
- `update_attribute` doesn't validate the record, calls **callbacks** and **saves**;
- `update_column` doesn't validate the record, doesn't call callbacks, **doesn't call save** method, though it **does update** record in the database.

If the only method that "works" is `update_column` my guess is that you have a callback somewhere that is throwing an error. Try to check your `log/development.log` file to see what's going on.

You can also use `update_attributes!`. This variant will throw an error, so it may give you information on why your model isn't saving.

You should use `update_attributes` and avoid the two other methods unless you know exactly what you are doing. If you add validations and callbacks later to your model, using `update_attribute` and `update_column` can lead to nasty behaviour that is really difficult to debug.

You can check [this link](http://maxivak.com/update_attribute-and-update_attributes-ruby-on-rails/) for more info on that.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Strangely, even with the bang update_attributes! isn't throwing an error. I can't spot any errors in my log file, either, though maybe I'm not reading it correctly. I've added the log to my post, if you wouldn't mind giving it a look.

Comment: I've updated question with more information. Specifically, I've put a condition into the controller so that it will throw errors if there are any. Instead, it acts like it's saving properly. Something is very strange here, right?

Comment: @timothythehuman Your condition is useless with the bang version. It will raise an error anyway if it can't save so you'll never get to the `@reply.errors` line. You should use the normal version if you want to print any errors. And yes, something *is* very strange...

Comment: Removed the bang, but it's giving me the "I am trying to update" message. Any other direction you can offer? I'll keep tinkering with this regardless. As you mention, falling on back on update_column is not ideal.

Comment: @timothythehuman When you say it works with `update_column` do you mean the object is rendered in the view or that it's saved in the database? Do you call `save` after `update_column`?

Comment: I mean it's saved to the database. With update_attributes it renders in the view but doesn't actually save. I've tried calling save as well, but with no effect.

Comment: @timothythehuman I'm sorry, your code looks correct, I don't have any more ideas about what could be going wrong... :(

Comment: Thanks for trying, though. I'll keep you posted when I figure this out.

Comment: This answer is WRONG or outdated in Rails 4: #update_column does save the record!

Comment: @collimarco Hey, don't be aggressive. The question is tagged 'ruby-on-rails-3' so yes, this is Rails 3 and not Rails 4.

Comment: @alestanis Sorry, it wasn't meant to be aggressive :) The problem is that there's a lot of confusion out there: if you are trying to understand the difference and you read this answer you get even more confused. Maybe the question should be updated to say that it refers to Rails 3, because the tag is not enough visible.

Comment: I am running into the same issue in Rails 3.2. The only difference is the column I am trying to update is a `:binary` column and I'm updating its value with `Marshal.dump(val)`. `update_column` works, but none of the other ways to update work. I initially thought it's an error specific to using `Marshal` on a `:binary` column, but I guess it's more widespread?

Comment: In your explanation for `update_column` what's the diff between "calling save method" and "updating the database"? @alestanis

Answer (score 0):

A gut guess would be to say that you have a mass assignment problem and should add your attributes in your model like this

```
attr_accessible: :your_attribute, :your_attribute2
```

Comment: That was my first guess, too. Unfortunately, I have made it (the only attribute I'm changing) attr_accessible. Thanks, anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but with Rails 4.  The issue happens when you have params[] in update_attribute.  In Rails 4 with strong parameters

```
@reply.update_attributes(params[reply_params])
```

should be

```
@reply.update_attributes(reply_params)
```

I'm not to familiar with Rails 3 but this should be the issue:

```
@reply.update_attributes(params[:reply])
```

should be

```
@reply.update_attributes(:reply)
```