# What is the best practice for same model: update_attributes or self.save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

Say I have to update 'author_id' in article model. From a method that belongs to `app/model/article.rb`

Which one should i prefer and why?

```
self.update_attribute(:author_id, id)
```

or

```
self.author_id = id
self.save
```

If there is even better way, please suggest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference is that `update_attribute` will not trigger validations. You should definitively prefer the second option (unless you really want to skip the validations). You can write in one line using `update_attributes` (note s at the end):

```
self.update_attributes(author_id: id)
```

There is also another methods worth knowing called `update_column(s)`. Those method will skip all the callbacks and validations and will save only specific columns in the database, leaving the rest unchanged (all other methods saves all the columns):

```
self.id    #=> 1
self.id = 5
self.update_column(:name, 'hello')
self.id    #=> 5
self.id_changed?    #=> true!
```

Comment: `update_attributes` does trigger callbacks, it only doesn't run validations.

Comment: thanks a lot. I really didn't know this about update_column. I think it should be best in my case, where i dont need any callbacks and validation and all i need to do is update a specific column! +1

Comment: @singhshivam - Just remember to be careful when you use them as they can easily make your stored models invalid.

Comment: thanks i will be careful. Also i found this: update_attributes tries to validate the record, calls callbacks and saves; update_attribute doesn't validate the record, calls callbacks and saves; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14415857/rails-update-column-works-but-not-update-attributes Hope its helpful. :)

Comment: @MarekLipka The documentation for `update_attributes` says "If the object is invalid, the saving will fail and false will be returned". Correct me if im wrong, but doesnt this mean that it invokes validations?

Comment: @Santosh - He meant `update_attribute`, not `update_attributes`. :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends. If you want your validations run, you should go with the second way (with `save`):

```
self.author_id = id
save
```

You can do it also in one line, using `update`:

```
update(author_id: id)
```

If you don't need them, you can use [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) (since [`update_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/update_attribute) doesn't run validations):

```
update_attribute(:author_id, id)
```

Comment: is there any difference in terms of performance, complexity? Which one will be more optimized? (say no validation needed) or it just comes to ones style of coding?

Comment: If no validation is needed, `update_attribute` is more eficient (since it doesn't run validations).